# How to sum time datatype in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have query which  gives sum of total talk time for an Agent all the years

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(s, SUM(( DATEPART(hh, TalkTime) * 3600 ) + ( DATEPART(mi, TalkTime) * 60 ) + DATEPART(ss, TalkTime)), 0))
  FROM [CRMIntegration].[dbo].[Five9CallLog]
  where AGENT_NAME = 'XYZ'
```

which is giving me '00:37:01.0000000'

but when i sum up total talk time for this year till now using the below query

```
SELECT 
CONVERT(TIME, DATEADD(s, SUM(( DATEPART(hh, TalkTime) * 3600 ) + ( DATEPART(mi, TalkTime) * 60 ) + DATEPART(ss, TalkTime)), 0))
  FROM [CRMIntegration].[dbo].[Five9CallLog]
  where AGENT_NAME = 'XYZ'
  and DateOfcall between 
  DATEADD(yy, DATEDIFF(yy,0,getdate()), 0) and dateadd(day,datediff(day,1,GETDATE()),0)
```

result of the query is '23:34:38.0000000',but this should be always less than or equal to the first result

Is the function i am using  for calculating total talk time is correct?

Comment: Some sample data would probably help here. It could be that your first result is larger than a day, but you're not seeing it since only dealing with `TIME`.  You should probably just take the some of the lowest increment you care about.

Comment: could you just use datediff(s, startTime, endTime) to get the number of seconds in between your start and end?

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your first result is greater than 1 day, but that is being truncated by using `TIME`.  Instead of adding seconds to `0` and converting to `TIME`, you could use `DATEDIFF()` to get total minutes:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(MINUTE,0,TalkTime)
```

Ideally you'd have a start/end time to use instead of `0`, because you'll run into an overflow if you need to get too precise and try starting from `0`.  If it's always relative to the start of the day, you can use:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(SECOND,CAST(TalkTime AS DATE),TalkTime)
```

Likewise, you could simply remove the `TIME` conversion from what you already have.